# How to use read in bash to assign only one determined letter to a variable?

Tags: bash

I want to read from terminal and store exactly 1 letter.
My approach `x=$(read -dx)` is not working and empty.

Comment: Use `read -rn 1 x`

Comment: Does the `-n1` makes the `-r` redundant here?

Comment: `x=$(read -rn 1 x)` is still empty.

Comment: @JohnGoofy avoid the `x=$(...)`. Just do `read -rn 1 x`

Comment: When you run `x=$(read -r x)`, you're starting a new subshell, reading from stdin and setting the `x` variable inside that child process... and then, in the parent shell, assigning *everything the subshell wrote to stdout* to `x` in the parent... except that your subshell didn't write anything to stdout at all, so what you're assigning is always empty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you anubhava, kvantour and Charls Duffy for your answers and comments especially for the hint of the subshell. At least `read -rn 1 x` is working as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

read takes the output variable as a parameter.  Try something like:

```
read x && echo ${x:0:1}
```

The above reads input from the command line, then takes the first character and echoes it.